# Java Lambda for spring-cloud version to 3.2.3/3.1.7 org/springframework/boot/ApplicationContextFactory: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I'm trying change version for spring-cloud-function-adapter-aws from 3.0.7.RELEASE to either 3.1.7 or 3.2.3 (as Spring Cloud Function Vulnerability CVE-2022-22963) but getting error as it is not able to find the class

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/spring framework/boot/ApplicationContextFactory
at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.FunctionalSpringApplication.(FunctionalSpringApplication.java:67)
at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.AbstractSpringFunctionAdapterInitializer.springApplication(AbstractSpringFunctionAdapterInitializer.java:378)
at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.AbstractSpringFunctionAdapterInitializer.initialize(AbstractSpringFunctionAdapterInitializer.java:121)
at org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.aws.SpringBootStreamHandler.initialize(SpringBootStreamHandler.java:61)
at org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.aws.SpringBootStreamHandler.handleRequest(SpringBootStreamHandler.java:53)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:

My Application.java

```
@ComponentScan
```

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}
```

}

FunctionConfiguration.java

@Configuration
public class FunctionConfiguration {
private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FunctionConfiguration.class);

```
@Autowired
ActionService service;

@Bean
public Function<APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent, APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent> containerService() {
    return value -> {
        try {
            APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent responseEvent = checkHttpMethod(value);
            if (responseEvent != null) {
                responseEvent.setBody("Option Method");
                return responseEvent;
            } else {
                return createResponseEvent(value);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent().withBody(e.getMessage()).withStatusCode(500)
                    .withHeaders(createResultHeader(value));
        }
    };
}

private APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent checkHttpMethod(APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent event) {
    APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent responseEvent = new APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent();
    if (event.getHttpMethod() != null && event.getHttpMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("options")) {
        responseEvent.setHeaders(createResultHeader(event));
        responseEvent.setStatusCode(200);
        return responseEvent;
    } else
        return null;
}

private APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent createResponseEvent(APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent event) {
    APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent responseEvent = new APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent();

    try {
        responseEvent = service.actionMethod(event);
        responseEvent.setHeaders(createResultHeader(event));
        return responseEvent;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error executing method", e);
        responseEvent.setHeaders(createResultHeader(event));
        responseEvent.setBody(e.getMessage());
        responseEvent.setStatusCode(500);
        return responseEvent;
    }

}

private Map<String, String> createResultHeader(APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent event) {
    Map<String, String> resultHeader = new HashMap<>();
    resultHeader.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
    resultHeader.put("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
    resultHeader.put("Vary", "Origin");
    
    try {
        String origin = event.getHeaders().get("origin");
        resultHeader.put("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("origin not exist to add");
    }
    resultHeader.put("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    logger.info(" Headers added ");
    return resultHeader;
}
```

}

pom.xml

4.0.0
com.app.lambda
springBootLambda
1.0.3
springBootLambda

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <aws-lambda-java-core.version>1.2.1</aws-lambda-java-core.version>
    <spring-cloud-function.version>3.0.7.RELEASE
    </spring-cloud-function.version>
    <wrapper.version>1.0.17.RELEASE</wrapper.version>
    <aws-lambda-java-events.version>2.2.7</aws-lambda-java-events.version>
    <aws-java-sdk-s3.version>1.11.792</aws-java-sdk-s3.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-json</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20090211</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-indexer</artifactId>
        <scope>optional</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-function-adapter-aws</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-cloud-function.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
        <version>${aws-lambda-java-core.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.672</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.672</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-events</artifactId>
        <version>${aws-lambda-java-events.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot.experimental</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-thin-layout</artifactId>
                    <version>${wrapper.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
                <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                <shadedClassifierName>shaded</shadedClassifierName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

serverless.yml

service: SpringBoot-Lambda
provider:
name: aws
runtime: java8
region: us-east-1
memory: 2048
timeout: 40

spring:
jpa:
hibernate.ddl-auto: update
generate-ddl: true
show-sql: true

## jar file that will be uploaded and executed on AWS

package:
artifact: target/{project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar

#define Lambda function
functions:
createMethod:
handler: org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.aws.SpringBootStreamHandler
events: # api gateway
- http:
path: pass
method: post
cors: true
environment: # environment variables
FUNCTION_NAME: SpringBoot-Lambda

Comment: Sorry for previous post edited too look better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to upgrade Spring Boot as well. You are using 2.3.0 and ApplicationContextFactory was added in 2.4, but 2.4.x is no longer supported.

You should upgrade to Spring Boot 2.5.12 or 2.6.6.

Comment: Error updating to 2.5.12

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.5.12:repackage (repackage) on project springbootService: Execution repackage of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.5.12:repackage failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.5.12:repackage: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Method org/springframework/boot/loader/thin/ThinLayout.getLibraryLocation(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/springframework/boot/loader/tools/LibraryScope;)Ljava/lang/String; is abstract

Comment: Similar problem. You also need to update Thin Launcher. 1.0.27.RELEASE is the latest at the time of writing.

Comment: Failed to Execute repackage of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.5.12:repackage failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.5.12:repackage: AbstractMethodError: Method org/springframework/boot/loader/thin/ThinLayout.getLibraryLocation(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/springframework/boot/loader/tools/LibraryScope;)Ljava/lang/String; is abstract
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.5.12

Comment: added stiil same issue 
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot.experimental</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-thin-launcher</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.27.RELEASE</version>
   </dependency>
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.5.12
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy

Comment: Deleting .m2 and running again fixed it.
Thankyou @Andy Wilkinson